# Working with an implicit data set in the neuMF model

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, dataset

Explicit data sets such as [MovieLens](https://grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/) work according to a ranking, for example a user gives one to five stars for a film.
Implicit data like [RetailRocket](https://www.kaggle.com/retailrocket/ecommerce-dataset), for example, work with events for example user looks at the article, adds it to the shopping cart, pays for the article.

I am currently working with the [`neuMF` model from TensorFlow](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official/recommendation).
This works with MovieLens. How do I put my implicit data set (RetailRocket) in the `neuMF` model ?

Do I have to convert the implicit data set to an explicit data set first?
(So ​​I give each event an assignment, for example addtoCart = 3, this would then be a ranking again)

If I don't need to convert it, how do I put these events (strings) into the model?